# Unhide/hide value in checkbox and group them using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have this checkbox, i want them to be group and hide and unhide for each of its content. For example when i load page first **All CARS** will set in default as checked. If i check eg: CARS all of the checked check-boxes will become hidden. and **CARS** which is connected its own `div` will be only show. If i uncheck a **CARS** it will be automatically check ***ALL CARS*** as default
[image]

this is my code now :

```
<legend>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-all" active>ALL CARS
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-cars" id = "select-cars" class = "select-cars  ">CARS
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-vans" id = "select-vans" class = "select-vans">VANS & PICKUP
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-suv" id = "select-suv" class = "select-suv">SUV & CROSSOVER
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-mpv" id = "select-mpv" class = "select-mpv">MPV
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-hybrid" id = "select-hybrid" class = "select-hybrid">HYBRID
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="select-performance" id = "select-performance" class = "select-performance">PERFORMANCE
    </label>
</legend>
```

and this is the javascript that i've tried. it's working tho but it's not enough.

```
$('.select-cars').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
    //  ^
       $('.type-cars').fadeOut('slow');

    else 
        $('.type-cars').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**UDPATE**

this is the divs that under each checkbox that i wanted to hide.

```
<div class = "type-cars"></div>
<div class = "type-mpv"></div>
<div class = "type-suv"></div>
<div class = "type-van"></div>
<div class = "type-hybrid"></div>
<div class = "type-performance"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with your `if condition`

1. its Wrong check you cant select something like this `!this` this must be like this `$(this)`
2. Your condition syntax fully wrong in jquery write something like this `if(condition){//some action} else {//some action which is not meet your if condition}`
3. **UPDATE:3** for OP's new requirement

```js
if ($(".select-allcars").prop('checked')) { // this if checking all car selected or nor when page load if yeas show all div
  $('.customdiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  selectedtype = $(this).val(); //this is selecting checked checkbox value when clicked on it
  long = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length; // this is checked checkbox lenght 

  $('.customdiv').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // when you click it it hides all div
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {  // this is checking if that checkbox checked or not
    $(".select-allcars").prop('checked', false); // if checked it uncheck all cars checkbox
    $('.' + selectedtype).addClass('visible') // in earlier mention this put value of checked checkbox in that select so we can select class of which one we checked then we give visible class of we select
  } else {
    if (long == 0) {// this is checking how many checkbox selected if its 0 it shows all div with checking all cars checkbox
      $('.select-allcars').prop('checked', true);
      $('.customdiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    $('.' + selectedtype).removeClass('visible')// this is removing visible class if checked checkbox lengh is not 0

  }



  if ($(this).hasClass('select-allcars')) { // when we click all cars check box its checking its class which is select-allcars if yes i unchecked all checked checkboxes and checking all cars checkbox also showing all div
    $('input').prop('checked', false);
    $('.select-allcars').prop('checked', true);
    $('.customdiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
});
```

```css
#myBttn {
  text-align: center;
  background: unset;
  border: unset;
}

.customdiv {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="select-all" checked class='select-allcars'>ALL CARS
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="type-cars" id="select-cars" class="select-cars  ">CARS
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="type-van" id="select-vans" class="select-vans">VANS & PICKUP
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="type-suv" id="select-suv" class="select-suv">SUV & CROSSOVER
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="type-mpv" id="select-mpv" class="select-mpv">MPV
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="type-hybrid" id="select-hybrid" class="select-hybrid">HYBRID
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="type-performance" id="select-performance" class="select-performance">PERFORMANCE
  </label>
</legend>
<div class="customdiv type-cars">cars pics</div>
<div class="customdiv type-mpv">mpv pics</div>
<div class="customdiv type-suv">suv pics</div>
<div class="customdiv type-van">van pics</div>
<div class="customdiv type-hybrid">hybrid pics</div>
<div class="customdiv type-performance">performance pics</div>
<div class="">div which is on your somewhere in your html no hide</div>
<div class="">div which is on your somewhere in your html no hide</div>
```

Comment: if i check the CARS it unhide the other checkbox ?? what i want is to hide the div for each checkbox. i'll update for you to see the divs. of each checkbox

Comment: no, what i want is to hide the div for each checkbox. i want to attach a div so i can hide/show it when i select each of them.

Comment: its working but i still have alot more question: 1. for example i select CARS what i want is to show only the car pics. and hide all of them. and show when i selected each of the other car selection . 2 .for example i have chosen only 1 selection like CARS then i unselect it . i wanted it to automatically SELECT the ALL CARS. and show all of the DIVS

Comment: @jmv edited but  dont know why you want to select all checkboxes after unchecked your recently checked your checkbox but here is what you seek

Comment: no man, what i want is to select ALL CARS checkbox. . because if i select it, it will show all the vehicle pics. not select all the boxes. sorry i guess it's a grammatical error

Comment: you got it!. but there are problems that occur 1. when selecting multiple checkboxes. i overlaps the currently selected. it must add the pics. 2: when you selected multiple checkboxes. and uncheck another. i reveals all the pics. it must unselect the selected pics only.

Comment: @jmv hey i am back sorry for late was doing my job i updated this if this help check this as answered

Comment: hey man! THANK YOU SO MUCH!. this is what i wanted. can you explain to me the logic behind this?

Comment: glad i helped for you

Comment: can i change this. cause if i put this div {
  visibility: hidden;
} on my css. all of my div will be affected?

Comment: You should give same css on your div which is contains those picture so 

``.sameclass { visibility:hidden}`` something like this

Comment: like this ? .type-cars, .type-mpv , .type-suv , .type-hybrid, .type-vans , .type-performance {
  visibility: hidden;
}. how bout the JS ? i tried changing it to class that covers them. still hiding all my divs?

Comment: can i use display:none ? instead of visibility ? so it dosen't takes up space in the layout.

Comment: Yes you can@jmv

Comment: tried this: .select-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: inline-block !important;
} its working but it's not showing the pics ? hmmm and initially it's blank

Comment: You should tried more buddy i have my own work to do keep going you will understand good luck , I helped your main question plus your side also side with side

Comment: sorry bout that. thanks alot and sorry to bother you ! :)